# Object created within a function disappears despite being passed further

Tags: swift, syntax, garbage-collection

Coming from a different language I got surprised by a silent bug where an object which is passed to a method as a callback suddenly is never called. The reference to a callback is somehow lost.

**Minimal (not runnable) example of a problem:**

```
class Foo: NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func bar() {
        let out = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        let delegate = Foo() //nonsensical in this case, in normal case diff. object will be used
        out.startRecording(to: /*...*/, recordingDelegate: delegate)

        //Result: delegate methods are never called
    }
}
```

**Minimal (not runnable) example of a "solution":**

```
class Foo: NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func bar() {
        let out = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        out.startRecording(to: /*...*/, recordingDelegate: self)

        //Result: delegate methods are called when approperiate
    }
}
```

**I'm puzzled...**

- Why does that happen?
- How to prevent such situation?
- Is such silent failure by design?

---

*This question stems from the [AVCaptureMovieFileOutput never calls delegate on screen recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59818119/avcapturemoviefileoutput-never-calls-delegate-on-screen-recording)*

Answer (score 1):

Most delgates are `weak` so that they do not create a retain cycle, see [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html). Most of this is assuming that the delegate storage for what you are using is `weak`.

In your first example the only strong reference to the object is held by the function `bar`, as the delegate is a weak reference. Once the function ends, the only remaining strong reference is gone and the object is free to be deleted.

```swift
class Foo: NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func bar() {
        let out = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        let delegate = Foo() //object created, and strong reference stored in variable called delegate
        out.startRecording(to: /*...*/, recordingDelegate: delegate) // object passed in and likely stored in a weak variable inside of the `out` object. This means it will not keep a strong reference to your Foo object.

        //Result: delegate methods are never called
    }// local variable called delegate goes out of scope, strong reference to your Foo object goes away, there are no more strong references, can be deleted.
}
```

In the second example when using `self` as the delegate, `self` is likely sticking around after the end of the `bar` function, so the delegate remains.

```swift
class Foo: NSObject, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {
    func bar() {
        let out = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
        out.startRecording(to: /*...*/, recordingDelegate: self) // pass `self`, which presumably has something else referencing it with a strong reference, so it stays alive

        //Result: delegate methods are called when approperiate
    } // `self` still has strong references to it (somewhere else) keeping it alive after the function call, so the weak reference that is being used to call the delegate methods can still operate! Yay!
}
```

Hopefully that answers the "why."

As for prevention, you need to make sure you keep a strong reference to any delegates (or weak variables) that you want to stay alive.

This behavior is by design as it is used to prevent retain cycles and memory leaks. When designing your own classes with delegates it is up to you to use `weak` appropriately to prevent retain cycles when necessary.

As for the silence of the failure, there are many cases where the delegates are optional, and it is not considered a failure for the delegate to be nil and for the delegate functions to not get called. Many times the functions are called like `delegate?.delegateMethod()` intentionally so that the function will be called if you want to have a delegate and it won't cause a problem if you don't want to have a delegate.